# index.html not linking with handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, handlebars.js

I'm having trouble using handlebars and understanding its connection to HTML. I wanted to copy a code I saw [here](http://jsfiddle.net/KxCs2/1/) and inserted the HTML in a file called index.html. However, I don't know if my syntax is wrong or I'm missing something, but my HTML file doesn't seem to be linking to the javascript file.
 It should display a button through which to connect to twitter and a pop-up window should appear, followed by a Twitter timeline. However when I click on the button nothing happens.

I realize this must be a really rookie mistake but I have tried everything and can't find the solution. Would someone please help me?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Será que sim?</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">   

<script src="handlebars-v1.1.2.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
<script src="oauth.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="connect">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-connect">Connect with twitter</button>
<p>If nothing happen after the connexion, it's maybe because the twitter rate limit exceeded</p>
</div>
<div id="res">
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for a term or hashtag" id="search" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn-search">Search</button>
    </span>
</div>
<div id="search-res"></div>
</div>

<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
<ul id="timeline">
{{#each statuses}}
    <li>
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{user.profile_image_url}}" />
        <span class="content">
            <span class="author">{{user.name}}</span>
            <span class="text">{{link text}}</span>
        </span>
    </li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
</script>

</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: *"However when I click on the button nothing happens.*" Here it's work. On twitter button click open popup and go to *"Authorize Tutorial-node to use your account?"* I think you block the popup in your browser.

Comment: How so, ketan? I'm sorry but I'm completely new to this so any kind of help is appreciated!

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Just refer this link. http://www.wikihow.com/Allow-Pop%E2%80%93ups and check chrome section.

Comment: Have just tried it and it's still not working. The things is i have tried doing this without handlebars and it works, the popup shows up as it should, and it works everytime I try it on jsfiddle. But whener I copy that code to my own files and get it running on MAMP it doesn't seem to connect to the .js file... That's why I think there must be something wrong with my html.

Comment: Ohh then see in your browser console you missed to include js or given wrong path or may be some error.

Comment: The console tells me this: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 
Could it have something to do with the last part of the .js file? Where it says "Replace URL by HTML link?"

Comment: Have you include this three external files in your HTML file which included in JSFiddle. http://i.stack.imgur.com/YFE6y.png

Comment: Yes, they are right after the CSS links. I have also tried placing them at the bottom but it's no good either

Comment: Just include them in head section. And check included url. either it is proper?

Comment: An mainly https://oauth.io/auth/download/latest/oauth.js may create issue. if not included properly

Comment: Included url? I think everything is in it's place, I really don't get why it's not working...